# webmin/virtualmin: How to install phpmyadmin that can manage all databases?

Tags: phpmyadmin, webmin, virtualmin

I have 2 linode accounts, both with webmin/virtualmin installed and hosting many different websites. On one of the two accounts I managed to have one of the domains host phpmyadmin. When I go to that domain, it shows the phpmyadmin login page and I can simply login with different mysql users and hence am able to manage different databases. But I totally forget how I did it.

Now I am trying to setup the same thing for the other linode account. What I tried to do is, after creating a virtual server that is to host phpmyadmin, I go to "install script" to install phpmyadmin, problem is, on "install option" page and  "database to manage" option, I can only choose one database, as shown in the picture:
[image]
After I install it, even login with "root", I can only see the database "a", but not other virtual servers' databases. I also tried going to webmin's "Mysql Database Servers" and "Database Permission"/"User Permission" settings, but it seems not related. I also examined the first linode account where phpmyadmin works for all databases but couldn't figure out how I configured it in the first place.